# How could zombie Randall be walking around after dying of a broken neck?

Tags: the-walking-dead, zombie

In the season two finale of *The Walking Dead*, Shane kills Randall by snapping his neck. Hours later, Daryl and Glenn find Randall, who has since become a zombie, up and mobile.  Daryl even identifies the cause of death as a broken neck.

Since becoming a zombie doesn't heal any injuries or afflictions, it seems to me that Randall should have become a zombie who was paralyzed from the neck down.  His head would still be reanimated (like Herschel's head was in the season four mid season premiere), but the rest of his body would have remained dead.

How could Randall get up and walk around after having his neck broken?

Comment: As you noted in [your answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93987/5184), it's likely a production error. This is backed up by the word of god [in my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/84912/5184) where Kirkman says that paralyzed people would still be paralyzed upon reanimation.

Comment: @phantom42 - I completely forgot about that question.  Oops.